# Sort bash output by a number extracted from a specific column

Tags: awk, grep, sort

I am new to bash and I am struggling with the following task:
The output from UGE looks like this:

```
mgenkin@bamdev2:~/projects/BrainFlowUtilities/BrainFlowSimulations$ qstat

job-ID     prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          
jclass                         slots ja-task-ID 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-----------------------------------------------------
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam11                                                     16 1
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam17                                                     16 2
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam13                                                     16 3
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam05                                                     16 4
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam08                                                     16 5
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam15                                                     16 6
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam21                                                     16 7
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam27                                                     16 8
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam12                                                     16 9
  5247 0.51599 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/21/2020 16:40:21 comp.q@bam22                                                     16 10
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam22                                                      1 1
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam22                                                      1 2
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 3
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam22                                                      1 4
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam20                                                      1 5
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 6
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam22                                                      1 7
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam20                                                      1 8
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 9
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam17                                                      1 10
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam15                                                      1 11
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam01                                                      1 12
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam20                                                      1 13
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 14
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam17                                                      1 15
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam15                                                      1 16
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam01                                                      1 17
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam20                                                      1 18
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 19
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam23                                                      1 20
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam17                                                      1 21
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam15                                                      1 22
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam01                                                      1 23
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam20                                                      1 24
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 25
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam23                                                      1 26
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam26                                                      1 27
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam17                                                      1 28
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam15                                                      1 29
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam03                                                      1 30
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam01                                                      1 31
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam28                                                      1 32
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam20                                                      1 33
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam27                                                      1 34
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam23                                                      1 35
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam26                                                      1 36
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam17                                                      1 37
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam15                                                      1 38
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam03                                                      1 39
 30995 0.50020 Genkin_Fit mgenkin      r     07/23/2020 13:12:08 comp.q@bam01                                                      1 40
```

I want to sort the output based on the number in queue column, so the first row should be with `q@bam01` and so on.

I don't understand how to it with grep/awk

Comment: You *can* sort with (GNU) awk, but not with grep. Is there any secondary sorting you want to do, given duplicates in the queue field? Will the leading text in that column always be "`comp.q@`", and if not, do you want the sorting to consider it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort by column 8 (the "queue" column), considering only the numeric portion, and assuming that the leading text is always "`comp.q@bam`" (10 characters), and there's only one space before that field, and to sort them numerically, you could use:

```
qstat | head -n 2
qstat | sed 1,2d | sort -k8.12,8.14n
```

The two separate calls to `qstat` are to print the two header lines first (so that they're not sorted with the data), then to sort the actual data (removing those first two header lines).  The sort is "keyed" (`-k`) on field 8, starting at position 12 and ending at position 14, with a `n`umeric sort. The key definition here counts the leading space before the "queue" field as position #1, so the actual numbers (in your sample) start at position 12. If your output could have longer numeric fields, adjust the ending range (`8.14`) upwards.

If this was something you wanted to keep around as something reusable, you could create a function:

```
function sortqstat() {
  qstat | head -n 2
  qstat | sed 1,2d | sort -k8.12,8.14n
}
```

Since the numeric portion appears to be zero-padded, you could try a simpler variation -- just tell `sort` to just sort field 8 generically:

```
qstat | sort -k8,8
```

This simplistic sort moves the headers around; to keep them separate, use separate calls like above. In this simplification, duplicate queue names will sort together, then numerically within them -- and not all strictly numerically if there are different queue names.

---

[glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) commented with an improvement -- a way to parse the output with only *one* call to `qstat`; I've modified their idea slightly, to this:

```
qstat | { IFS= read -r header1; 
          IFS= read -r header2; 
          printf "%s\n" "$header1" "$header2"; 
          sort -k8,8; }
```

This opens a pipe from qstat to a command group (surrounded in braces `{}`); that command group reads the first two lines, into the variables header1 and header2, then prints those header lines. Since those lines are now gone from the input, the subsequent `sort` command has only the data left to sort. I found it more obvious to explicitly read the two header lines, but you could do a simple "read and print" twice, or with a loop.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for a detailed and complete response! I still have one question about the method with two calls. It seems to me that these two calls are independent - so I don't see a reason calling `qstat | head -n 2`. Every call to qstat prompts it to print brand new ouput with all the lines, incluiding the first two.  Even if I only call the second command, my result appears to be the same.

Comment: The idea is just to print the header lines by themselves, with the first call. The second call only gets the data lines, and sorts them.  That way, you have the header(s) and the sorted data. It'd be simpler if you were OK with dropping the header lines altogether.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks